# QEMU frequency mismatch on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, android-studio, qemu

I have the following message on my Kubuntu 17.10 - I googled the message but unfortunately hits are way too technical for me to find a solution:

```
Emulator: qemu-system-i386: warning: TSC frequency mismatch between VM
(2394456 kHz) and host (2394457 kHz), and TSC scaling unavailable
```

With the following symptom:
[image]

At first launch everything worked well in this regard, so I don't know what caused the issue and how to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the solution via a workaround!

**tl;dr version**: `-use-system-libs` option with the emulator is a temporary workaround.

**longer version**:

Googling *TSC frequency mismatch* gave no ideas as to what might cause the issue. Disabling HW acceleration was one possible fix, but the result is a slow emulation. I gave it some rest but then I figured this should be a kernel related issue, since it was KVM that seemed to cause the issue.
I tried disabling intel microcode driver (no help) and a kernel update (no help), but after the latter, at least I got little less cryptic error messages like:

```
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
21:31   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
21:31   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
21:31   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
21:31   Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
21:31   Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
21:31   Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  64
21:31   Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  65
21:31   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

So this must be a driver issue! Googling the first error message gave me [this hit](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213192), using  `-use-system-libs` with the emulator. It's working now! But, how to make it permanent? [This page](https://mike42.me/blog/how-to-edit-emulator-flags-in-android-studio) also pointed me to the right direction: use a wrapper script to launch the emulator. Now everything works like a charm.

So, step-by-step solution:

1. in terminal: `/home/$user/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds` to find your AVD-s - the names might differ from those apparent in Android Studio. Find the name of the AVD you have trouble with. Note that the emulator path might differ as well, based on the path you have specified during AStudio installation.
2. test if the following works for you as a manual workaround:  `/home/$user/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd your_emulator_name_here -use-system-libs`
3. if (2) works for you, rename the original emulator file and launch it from a shell script for permanent option flag launch (your path and text editor might differ):

   `$ cd /home/$user/Android/Sdk/emulator/
    $ mv emulator emulator.0
    $ touch emulator
    $ chmod +x emulator
    $ kate emulator`

insert the following and save:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
$0.0 $@ -use-system-libs
```

Now every time the emulator is called it is done so with the system libs through the shell script named *emulator*, and it should give no errors from now on.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: any time the emulator is called? even from android studio?

Comment: it must be updates from android studio, android SDK or system libs that broke this fix.

Comment: Should work even from Studio. Linux does not specify file extensions like windows, therefore the trick should be able to work. I will updating my studio tomorrow and get back with feedback.

Comment: Happened to me all the sudden on AS 4.0, Ubuntu 20.04. Probably easier ways to fix, but this was the first thing I tried, and it worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem due to some updates, I opened my **Android Virtual Device Manager** from **Android Studio** (Tools->AVD Manager) then matched the emulator where the problem occurred. I clicked the **dropdown icon** from **Actions** column and selected the **Wipe Data** option.

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 4):

Go to **AVD Manager**, click the AVD that is causing this issue, and select **Wipe Data** from the options.